# Run a screen session on boot from rc.local

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I am trying to run a detached screen under a specific user in rc.local on boot. The code below is what I have so far, but it is not working for me. The su part seems to be giving me an error.

```
su - username -c /usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '/var/www/path/to/script/script.sh; exec bash'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think both `-c` parameters (`su` and `bash`) will have to be quoted at a minimum.

```
su - username -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '/var/www/path/to/script/script.sh; exec bash'"
```

Also `-` is expected to be last and may not be desirable here (see `man su`).

---

A few more remarks. `sudo` *could* be a better choice for a one-shot command like yours, but not necessarily:

```
sudo -iu username /usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '/var/www/path/to/script/script.sh; exec bash'
```

In particular, you can use one less level of quoting with `sudo`.

Another thing you want to be careful with is executing commands without absolute path in a privileged context. This holds for `su` (or `sudo`) but also for the path to `bash` in your command. You are doing it right with `screen`.

Just tested the following and it works nicely. I think the `-` is the main issue in your original line:

```
/bin/su username -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS test bash -c '/home/username/test.sh; exec bash'"
```

---

**Evil remark:** why don't you give [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) a try? I have recently switched and never looked back. The only thing I needed to change immediately was the prefix key combination which in `tmux` defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> - back to GNU `screen`'s <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

It allows splitting your window into an almost arbitrary number of panes (vertically *and* horizontally) and its configuration file format (including the one for the status par) is actually intelligible to humans. Of course `tmux` is as good as `screen` when you simply want to run some program/script not originally written as daemon in background. If you intend to interact with the terminal multiplexer, however, I warmly recommend `tmux`.

Comment: I will give this a try in a few. The script I am running uses absolute paths, so would you recommend `su` or `sudo`?

Comment: `sudo` is not a good choice if run from rc.local where you already are root, since you will miss a login shell. On a side note, have a look at `/etc/init/tty1.conf` - replace [a]getty with screen here.

Comment: @aquaherd: it's what I had in mind when I wrote *but not necessarily*. The clue, really, is in the usual `sudo su -` ... `sudo` (superuser do), `su` (switch user) ... good idea about the .conf

Comment: I have to say, I'm +1ing this post just because of your evil remark. I love it! It's a great replacement to screen, since one can force it to start a new session.

Comment: @aquaherd `sudo` can start a login shell just fine using `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I used I found it to be the cleanest and simplest (tested working myself):

Replace "user" with the user to run it as.
Replace "nameyouchoose" as the name of the screen session
Replace "/script/start.bash" to the path of your script.

```
/usr/bin/sudo -u user /usr/bin/screen -dmS nameyouchoose /script/start.bash
```

Source:
http://realtechtalk.com/How_to_start_screen_in_bash_script_or_from_etcrclocal_on_startup_as_a_specific_user-1980-articles

Answer (score 2):

Starting a script in a new detached screen as current user (rc.local = root):

`screen -dmS <session name> <command>`, example:

> `screen -dmS screenName bash /home/user/run.sh`

---

Starting a script from rc.local as `user`:

> `runuser -l user -c 'screen -dmS screenName bash /home/user/run.sh'`

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -u username` instead of `su - username`