# Xdotool does not minimize terminal window when using in Startup Application when pc boots?

Tags: command-line

Based on feedback in comments tried this command:   In a terminal window this works:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "sudo ./serial"; xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

However when running the command in Startup Program the xdotool seems to be ignored. The pc boots with terminal windows on the screen, not minimized.

Background History:

I'm trying to determine a way to minimize the terminal window with the *gnome-terminal* command. I need my Ubuntu 14.04LTS remote pc to run several scripts and a C program at startup.  This remote pc is for customer viewing so the monitor needs to be clean. I did not see an option available to minimize: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html.  The best I could do was to make the terminal windows small, which is acceptable if I don't find a better way.  This is my command entered into Ubuntu's "Startup Applications" program:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=60x2 --command "sudo ./My_C_Program"
```

My programming/Linux skills are mediocre, but growing. I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Based on a comment/feedback tried this:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c  "sudo ./serial_ver2_machine3_free_air_3_95"; wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,shaded
```

This works just the way I want when executing in a Terminal window!! The Terminal window is shaded but program is still running and it reappears when I click twice on Ubuntu's Terminal icon.

However when executing within "Startup Applications" the Terminal window is not 'shaded'.  Using 'add,hidden' does not work.  Using 'add,below' works,  except I'm using my desktop background image as part of the customer viewing.

Comment: Run the command at login ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login

Comment: Maybe using `wmctrl`, like `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,hidden` or `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,below`?

Comment: Does this command need to be run inside a terminal?

Comment: I doesn't need to run in terminal, but I remotely monitor with Teamviewer and access the terminal window and see/search print messages.  I do export print messages to a log file, so I probably don't need it to run in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to create `tmux` session at system startup and execute some commands inside. Then you will be able to attach to this session no matter whether within `ssh` or `gnome-terminal`. `tmux` has more advanced usage, here I will try to cover the most basic level.

**1.** Install `tmux`: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install tmux`

**2.** Create auxiliary executable script file. Let's assume it is placed in user's `$HOME` directory and it is called `run-my-tmux-session`:

```bsh
touch "$HOME/run-my-tmux-session"
chmod +x "$HOME/run-my-tmux-session"
```

The script should look as this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

SESS="my-tmux-session"                               # Set the session name

if (tmux has-session -t "$SESS" 2> /dev/null); then  # If session with name $SESS doesn't 
        echo "Session '$SESS' exists."               # exists
else                                                 # create it and send few commands
        tmux new-session -d -s $SESS
        tmux send-keys -t $SESS "echo 'Now:'; while true; do printf '%(%c)T\r'; done" ENTER
fi

exit 0
```

**3.** Now if you execute `~/run-my-tmux-session` the script will create `tmux` session, called `my-tmux-session` and will execute few commands inside it. Here are few hints:

- To list all sessions: `tmux ls`
- To kill a session or to kill all sessions:

  ```bsh
  tmux kill-session -t <session-name>
  tmux kill-session #
  ```
- To attach to an existing session:

  ```bsh
  tmux a -t <session-name>
  tmux attach -t <session-name>
  ```
- To leave (detach) session run the follow command from within the session: **`tmux detach`**
- To send a command to a session without attaching:

  ```bsh
  tmux send -t <sess-name> "<commands>" ENTER
  tmux send-keys -t <sess-name> "<commands>" ENTER
  ```

**4.A.** Launch the `tmux` session from *Startup Applications*. Open [*Startup Applications*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6CW3.png) and create a new entry. Its command should be *(replace `<user>` with the actual username)*:

```bsh
/home/<user>/run-my-tmux-session
```

**4.B.** Launch the `tmux` session from `crontab` on reboot. Edit the user's `crontab` file and add the following lines to the bottom *(type `crontab -e` to access user's `crontab`)*:

```bsh
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot "$HOME/run-my-tmux-session"
```

**4.C.** Launch the `tmux` session from `/etc/rc.local`. **This is probably the best solution!** Edit the file `/etc/rc.local` and add [one of the following lines](https://askubuntu.com/a/261905/566421) before the last line in the file, that is `exit 0` *(replace `<user>` with the actual username)*:

```bsh
su -l <user> -c "/home/<user>/run-my-tmux-session"
```

```bsh
sudo -iu <user> "/home/<user>/run-my-tmux-session"
```

---

References:

- [Start detached Tmux](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278419) | [Tmux login script](http://stahlke.org/dan/tmux-session/) | [Create session if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993915/6543935) | [Command in detached Tmux](https://serverfault.com/questions/339390/run-command-in-detached-tmux-session)
- [ArchWiki Tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Start_tmux_on_every_shell_login) | [A Guide to Customizing your Tmux.conf](http://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-guide-to-customizing-your-tmux-conf/) | [A Gentle Introduction to Tmux](https://hackernoon.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-tmux-8d784c404340)
- [TMUX config file](https://gist.github.com/snuggs/800936) | [Another example](https://gist.github.com/spicycode/1229612) | [**Tmux Shortcuts & Cheatsheet**](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058), also [here](https://gist.github.com/henrik/1967800) & [here](https://gist.github.com/andreyvit/2921703)

Further reading:

- [Keep running a python program even after logging-off the ssh session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921494/keep-running-a-python-program-even-after-logging-off-the-ssh-session)
- [How to keep processes running after ending ssh session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)

Comment: I made the script as you described and used option 4.A and it started my c program and running in the background through tmux.  tmux worth learning and utilizing.  Solved!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround that uses `xdotool`: Create an auxiliary startup script, that will be executed within a `gnome-terminal`, which is opened by *Startup Applications*. The script will execute some commands and will minimize the active window. Please read carefully the comments within the script's body bellow.

**1.** Install `xdotool`: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install xdotool`

**2.** Create auxiliary executable script file. Let's assume it is placed in user's `$HOME` directory and it is called `run-and-minimize`:

```bsh
touch "$HOME/run-and-minimize"
chmod +x "$HOME/run-and-minimize"
```

The script should look as this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Put your commands here, for example:
echo 'The current time is:'

sleep 2                                            # Adjust this value. The mouse should not be moved while this period otherwise some other window could become active!
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)  # Minimize the window

# Or put your commands here, for example:
while true; do printf '%(%c)T\r'; done &           # Some commands must be pushed into the background (`&`) to be successfully interrupted with keep open the terminal window.

exec bash                                          # Keep the window open after the above commands are finished or interrupted
```

**3.** Open [*Startup Applications*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6CW3.png) and create a new entry. Its command should be:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'exec $HOME/run-and-minimize'
```

I also successfully have tested:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'exec $HOME/run-and-minimize'
```

---

References:

- [What is the command to minimize the gnome terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318062/what-is-the-command-to-minimize-the-gnome-terminal)

Comment: This command typed in a terminal window works:         gnome-terminal -x bash -c  "sudo ./serial"; xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize       However when running the command in Startup Program the xdotool seems to be ignored.  The pc boots with terminal windows on the screen.

Comment: Hi, @Quickseal, I'm asking just from curiosity. Have you tried this solution? It's interesting in which cases it shall not work.

Comment: Hello, @pa4080.  I did try your steps but struggled in getting it working, so I decided to try the tmux option.  It may be my fault getting all the syntax correct in the bash script, so for other's looking at this, it may work for them.

Comment: Worked like a charm. you might have to use `xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize ` instead of `xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)`. https://askubuntu.com/a/912919/598062