# How do I start a persistent terminal running service on a headless server?

Tags: server, hibernate

I have a headless media server running ubuntu 18.04.  I'd like to run a power management service on it so it suspends or hibernates 10 - 15 minutes after all the disks spin down.  sspender works well for this but there's a problem.  It has to be launched from a terminal window, and is only active while that terminal is open.  It will survive suspend/wake cycles but not a reboot.  I have to relaunch it manually.  Can anyone tell me how to do that remotely so it stays running?  It's not convenient to haul a monitor and keyboard into my laundry room every time I reboot.

I can launch it from SSH, or by opening a terminal on a remote desktop connection.  However the process is killed as soon as I disconnect either session.

I've tried launching it at boot with Crontab entries but it doesn't work.

I've also tried Powernap, but can't get that to work at all.

Comment: `nohup sspender &`?

Comment: Or lookup how to run the *screen* application.

Answer (score 1):

The above suggestions by AlexP and user535733 both work.

With *screen* I start it, detach the screen session, and close the SSH browser.  Have to remember not to close the screen session, just detach it.

*Nohup* works, although the log file can grow quite large since the output is pretty verbose.  I think there's a way to direct it to *null* and no log is created.  Still testing that.

Thank you both very much for your help.

Comment: C. La Mosca's answer shows how to redirect `nohup`'s output and stderror to `/dev/null`. In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/962820/566421) are shown few ideas how to create `tmux` session and execute a command inside during the system startup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enoughreputation to comment.

Like AlexP sugested i think `nohup` is the key.

did you tried?

```
# nohup sspender &> /dev/null &
```